# How can I convert a text-file outline list into a recursive collection of objects?

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview, design-patterns

How can I convert this **text file** content into a **recursive collection of objects** that I can bind to a **TreeView**? i.e. I want to end up with a collection of **3 objects**, the first one called **countries** which has a collection of three child objects: **france**, **germany**, **italy**, and so on...

**ANSWER:** thanks to all who helped out on this, here's my code that successfully parses this text outline into a XAML tree: http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=358

```
countries
-france
--paris
--bordeaux
-germany
-italy
subjects
-math
--algebra
--calculus
-science
--chemistry
--biology
other
-this
-that
```

The **code below** is as far as I got it, but it is not dealing with multiple children of parents correctly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TestRecursive2342
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<OutlineObject> outlineObjects = new List<OutlineObject>();

            //convert file contents to object collection
            List<string> lines = Helpers.GetFileAsLines();
            Stack<OutlineObject> stack = new Stack<OutlineObject>();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                OutlineObject oo = new OutlineObject(line);

                if (stack.Count > 0)
                {
                    OutlineObject topObject = stack.Peek();
                    if (topObject.Indent < oo.Indent)
                    {
                        topObject.OutlineObjects.Add(oo);
                        stack.Push(oo);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stack.Pop();
                        stack.Push(oo);                        
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    stack.Push(oo);
                }

                if(oo.Indent == 0)
                    outlineObjects.Add(oo);
            }

            outlineObjects.ForEach(oo => Console.WriteLine(oo.Line));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class OutlineObject
    {
        public List<OutlineObject> OutlineObjects { get; set; }
        public string Line { get; set; }
        public int Indent { get; set; }

        public OutlineObject(string rawLine)
        {
            OutlineObjects = new List<OutlineObject>();
            Indent = rawLine.CountPrecedingDashes();
            Line = rawLine.Trim(new char[] { '-', ' ', '\t' });
        }
    }

    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static List<string> GetFileAsLines()
        {
            return new List<string> {
                "countries",
                "-france",
                "--paris",
                "--bordeaux",
                "-germany",
                "-italy",
                "subjects",
                "-math",
                "--algebra",
                "--calculus",
                "-science",
                "--chemistry",
                "--biology",
                "other",
                "-this",
                "-that"};
        }

        public static int CountPrecedingDashes(this string line)
        {
            int tabs = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var c in line)
            {
                if (c == '-')
                    tabs++;
                else
                    break;
            }
            return tabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public Item Parent;
}

List<Item> Collection = new List<Item>();

public void Main()
{
    var DataSource = data.InnerText;

    StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(MapPath("_test2.txt"));
    int LastLevel = 0;

    while (Reader.EndOfStream == false) {
        var line = Reader.ReadLine();
        var Level = line.Where((System.Object c) => c == "-").Count;
        Item LastItem = default(Item);

        if (Collection.Count != 0) {
            LastItem = Collection.Last();
        }

        if (Level == 0) {
            Collection.Add(new Item { Name = line });
            LastLevel = 0;
        }
        else if (Level - LastLevel == 1) {
            Collection.Add(new Item { Name = line, Parent = LastItem });
            LastLevel += 1;
        }
        else if (Level == LastLevel) {
            Collection.Add(new Item { Name = line, Parent = LastItem.Parent });
        }
        else if (Level < LastLevel) {
            var LevelDiff = LastLevel - Level;
            Item Parent = LastItem;

            for (i = 0; i <= LevelDiff; i++) {
                Parent = Parent.Parent;
            }

            LastLevel = Level;
            Collection.Add(new Item { Name = line, Parent = Parent });
        }
    }

    Reader.Close();
}
```

This should do the trick. I tested it on your text file. There might be some bugs. Test it and tell if it works.

EDIT: Actually after further testing it turns out this does not work as expected. You need to add more logic to make it work. I leave that to you.

EDIT: After testing the code a bit more I have come to a version that works better. I still cannot guarantee that It will work under all circumstances.

Comment: thanks, I used your if/else pattern to restructure my code and got it to work: http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=358

Answer (score 1):

You should make your `OutlineObject` contain a list of child `OutlineObject`s. This way you can bind to the child collection in tree views.

Look [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/05/05/binding-a-treeview-to-a-dataset/) for an example. Or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972151.aspx).

---

For parsing, you should maintain a `Stack<OutlineObject>` of your nested objects.
When you read next `OutlineObject`, look at the depth of the last `OutlineObject` in the stack. If your level is greater, you add yourself as a child of that `OutlineObject`, and push your `OutlineObject` onto the stack. If your level is the same, you remove that `OutlineObject` and push your object instead. If your level is bigger, you remove that top stack `OutlineObject`, and repeat the check.

---

Regarding your change to add

> ```
> if (topObject.Indent < oo.Indent) 
> { 
>   topObject.OutlineObjects.Add(oo); 
>   stack.Push(oo); 
> } 
> else 
> { 
>   stack.Pop(); 
>   stack.Push(oo); 
> }
> ```

...this code doesn't check for the case when the level of new object is smaller than the level of stack top. You'll need:

```
...
else if (topObject.Indent == oo.Indent) 
{ 
  stack.Pop(); 
  stack.Push(oo); 
} 
else 
{ 
  while (stack.Top().Indent >= oo.Indent) 
    stack.Pop(); 
  stack.Push(oo); 
}
```

Comment: yes OutlineObject has "public List<OutlineObject> OutlineObjects { get; set; }" and I've built a set of recursive OutlineObjects by hand and bound them successfully to a TreeView, but what I want to do now is convert a text list into that recursive collection.

Comment: great, that got me a lot farther, I posted my code above, it now gets three root children but the deeper children/parent relationships are not right for some reason, will work on it, thanks.

Comment: Consider tracking the last node that was added. You can then compare it to the current node to see if the new node is another sub child. If you want you can reuse the stack to perform this tracking.

Comment: Your code doesn't check for the case when the level of new object is **smaller** than the level of stack top.

Comment: You've got: `if (topObject.Indent < oo.Indent) { topObject.OutlineObjects.Add(oo); stack.Push(oo); } else {  Pop(); stack.Push(oo); }`. But you need `... else if if (topObject.Indent == oo.Indent) {  stack.Pop(); stack.Push(oo); } else { while (stack.Top().Indent >= oo.Indent) stack.Pop(); stack.Push(oo); }`

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Create a list of OutlineObject objects, one for each level, these will serve as the parents.

So, the algorithm:

1. Create the object from the line
2. Find the level of indentation (which will be 0 for root objects)
3. If the list of parents has less than level+1 number of elements, add "null" elements until it has enough (which means that for the first root object, add a "null" element to make it have 1 element)
4. Replace element #level in that list with the new object you created in 1. (since the list is 0-based, the root objects will be the first ones)
5. If level is > 0, add it as a child to parents[level-1], if level == 0, add it as a root object

This should give you your tree structure. You will need to keep a child-list in each object.

Also note that the above list will need additional error checking if you want it to handle errors in the file, like this:

```
root
-child 1
--child 2
another root
--child 3 (note that we skipped a level)
```

In this case, the last child there will be added as a child of "child 1", not of "another root".

Comment: right, in my code I'm doing step 1 and 2, but in step 3, what do you mean by "list of parents", I'm keeping a list of children in each object, do you mean to keep track of a list of parents as well?

Comment: No, during the read-process, you simply keep a list of the parents of each level. Whenever you encounter a new root (level 0) object, you replace the object in that list. Whenever you encounter a new level 1 object, you use the object in that list on level 0 as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

The Composite pattern is the first thing that comes to mind for me...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt which is a combination of your original effort plus diamandiev's approach. I also added a recursive Output() method which will effectively reproduce the original input file.

Unfortunately I couldn't quite fathom the stack approach, but would be interested to see a working example.

Note that this only allows for your given example of nodes being nested 3 levels deep. Any more than that will require a modification to the `else if ((oo.Indent - lastItem.Indent) < 0)` check.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TestRecursive2342
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<OutlineObject> outlineObjects = new List<OutlineObject>();

            //convert file contents to object collection 
            List<string> lines = Helpers.GetFileAsLines();

            OutlineObject lastItem = new OutlineObject();
            bool processOk = true;

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                OutlineObject oo = new OutlineObject(line);

                if (lastItem.Indent != -1)
                {
                    if (oo.Indent == 0 && lastItem.Indent != 0)
                    {
                        // we've got a new root node item, so add the last item's top level parent to the list
                        while (lastItem.parent != null)
                            lastItem = lastItem.parent;

                        outlineObjects.Add(lastItem);
                    }
                    else if ((oo.Indent - lastItem.Indent) == 1)
                    {
                        // new item is one level lower than the last item
                        oo.parent = lastItem;
                        lastItem.OutlineObjects.Add(oo);
                    }
                    else if (oo.Indent == lastItem.Indent)
                    {
                        // new item is at the same level as the last item
                        oo.parent = lastItem.parent;
                        lastItem.parent.OutlineObjects.Add(oo);
                    }
                    else if ((oo.Indent - lastItem.Indent) < 0)
                    {
                        // new item is above the last item, but not a root node
                        // NB: this only allows for an item to be two levels above the last item
                        oo.parent = lastItem.parent.parent;
                        lastItem.parent.parent.OutlineObjects.Add(oo);
                    }
                    else if ((oo.Indent - lastItem.Indent) > 1)
                    {
                        // missing node check
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: missing node in input file between \"{0}\" and \"{1}\"", lastItem.Line, oo.Line);
                        processOk = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                lastItem = oo;
            }

            if (processOk)
            {
                // flush the last item
                while (lastItem.parent != null)
                    lastItem = lastItem.parent;

                outlineObjects.Add(lastItem);

                outlineObjects.ForEach(oo => oo.Output());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class OutlineObject
    {
        public OutlineObject parent { get; set; }
        public List<OutlineObject> OutlineObjects { get; set; }

        public string Line { get; set; }
        public int Indent { get; set; }

        public void Output()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append('-', this.Indent);
            sb.Append(this.Line);

            Console.WriteLine(sb);

            foreach (OutlineObject oChild in this.OutlineObjects)
            {
                oChild.Output();
            }
        }

        public OutlineObject()
        {
            parent = null;
            OutlineObjects = new List<OutlineObject>();
            Line = "";
            Indent = -1;
        }

        public OutlineObject(string rawLine)
        {
            OutlineObjects = new List<OutlineObject>();
            Indent = rawLine.CountPrecedingDashes();
            Line = rawLine.Trim(new char[] { '-', ' ', '\t' });
        }
    }

    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static List<string> GetFileAsLines()
        {
            return new List<string> { 
                "countries", 
                "-france", 
                "--paris", 
                "--bordeaux", 
                "-germany", 
                "-italy", 
                "subjects", 
                "-math", 
                "--algebra", 
                "--calculus", 
                "-science", 
                "--chemistry", 
                "--biology", 
                "other", 
                "-this", 
                "-that"};
        }

        public static int CountPrecedingDashes(this string line)
        {
            int tabs = 0;

            foreach (var c in line)
            {
                if (c == '-')
                    tabs++;
                else
                    break;
            }
            return tabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What a great solution! This could make for a handy little utility. It's perfect.

I know it's been a while since you posted this; I wasn't able to locate the original but I found a copy archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100301175039/http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=358).

I've modified it a bit for brevity and translated it to VB.NET for those who may be interested.

Here's the end result:

**Main**

```
Module Main
  Sub Main()

    With New Test
      .Render()
    End With

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.Write("Press any key to exit...")
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
End Module
```

**Test**

```
Public Class Test
  Private ReadOnly Tree As Tree

  Public Sub New()
    Me.Tree = New Tree(Me.Text, "-", 1)
  End Sub



  Public Sub Render()
    Me.Render(Me.Tree.Nodes)
  End Sub



  Public Sub Render(Nodes As List(Of Node))
    Nodes.ForEach(Sub(Node As Node)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", Space(Node.Level), Node.Text)

                    Me.Render(Node.Nodes)
                  End Sub)
  End Sub



  Private ReadOnly Property Text As String
    Get
      Return _
        "TEST DATA" & vbCrLf &
        "countries" & vbCrLf &
        "-france" & vbCrLf &
        "--paris" & vbCrLf &
        "--bordeaux" & vbCrLf &
        "-germany" & vbCrLf &
        "--hamburg" & vbCrLf &
        "--berlin" & vbCrLf &
        "--hannover" & vbCrLf &
        "--munich" & vbCrLf &
        "-italy" & vbCrLf &
        "subjects" & vbCrLf &
        "-math" & vbCrLf &
        "--algebra" & vbCrLf &
        "--calculus" & vbCrLf &
        "-science" & vbCrLf &
        "--chemistry" & vbCrLf &
        "--biology" & vbCrLf &
        "other" & vbCrLf &
        "-this" & vbCrLf &
        "-that"
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

**Tree**

```
Public Class Tree
  Private Level As Integer

  Public Sub New(Text As String, LevelIndicator As String)
    Me.New(Text, LevelIndicator, 0)
  End Sub



  Public Sub New(Text As String, LevelIndicator As String, StartingIndex As Integer)
    Me.Load(Text, LevelIndicator, StartingIndex)
  End Sub



  Public ReadOnly Property Nodes As List(Of Node)
    Get
      Return _Nodes
    End Get
  End Property
  Private ReadOnly _Nodes As New List(Of Node)



  Private Sub Load(Text As String, LevelIndicator As String, StartingIndex As Integer)
    Dim iLevel As Integer
    Dim oParents As Stack(Of Node)
    Dim oNode As Node

    oParents = New Stack(Of Node)

    Text.ToLines(StartingIndex).ForEach(Sub(Line As String)
                                          oNode = New Node(Line, LevelIndicator)

                                          If oNode.Level = 0 Then ' Root '
                                            Me.Nodes.Add(oNode)
                                            oParents.Push(oNode)
                                            Me.Level = 0

                                          ElseIf oNode.Level - Me.Level > 1 Then ' Skipped generation(s) '
                                            Throw New FormatException("The outline structure is invalid.")

                                          ElseIf oNode.Level = Me.Level Then ' Sibling '
                                            oParents.Pop()
                                            Me.Level = oParents.SetNode(oNode, Me.Level)

                                          ElseIf oNode.Level - Me.Level = 1 Then ' Child '
                                            Me.Level = oParents.SetNode(oNode, Me.Level + 1)

                                          ElseIf oNode.Level < Me.Level Then ' Walk back up the stack '
                                            For iLevel = 0 To Me.Level - oNode.Level
                                              oParents.Pop()
                                            Next

                                            Me.Level = oParents.SetNode(oNode, oNode.Level)

                                          End If
                                        End Sub)
  End Sub
End Class
```

**Node**

```
Public Class Node
  Public Sub New(Line As String, LevelIndicator As String)
    _Level = Line.PrefixCount(LevelIndicator)
    _Text = Line.StripPrefix(LevelIndicator)
  End Sub



  Public ReadOnly Property Nodes As List(Of Node)
    Get
      Return _Nodes
    End Get
  End Property
  Private ReadOnly _Nodes As New List(Of Node)



  Public ReadOnly Property Level As Integer
    Get
      Return _Level
    End Get
  End Property
  Private ReadOnly _Level As Integer



  Public ReadOnly Property Text As String
    Get
      Return _Text
    End Get
  End Property
  Private ReadOnly _Text As String
End Class
```

**Extensions**

```
Public Module Extensions
  <Extension>
  Public Function PrefixCount(Text As String, Prefix As String) As Integer
    Dim iIndex As Integer

    PrefixCount = 0

    Do While Text.StartsWith(Prefix)
      iIndex = Text.IndexOf(Prefix)

      If iIndex = -1 Then
        Exit Do
      Else
        Text = Text.Substring(iIndex + Prefix.Length)
        PrefixCount += 1
      End If
    Loop
  End Function



  <Extension>
  Public Function StripPrefix(Text As String, Prefix As String) As String
    StripPrefix = Text

    Do While StripPrefix.StartsWith(Prefix)
      StripPrefix = StripPrefix.Substring(Prefix.Length)
    Loop
  End Function



  <Extension>
  Public Function ToLines(Text As String, StartingIndex As Integer) As List(Of String)
    Return Split(Text, vbCrLf).Where(Function(Line As String)
                                       Return Line.IsNullOrWhiteSpace = False
                                     End Function).Skip(StartingIndex).ToList
  End Function



  <Extension>
  Public Function SetNode(Parents As Stack(Of Node), Node As Node, Level As Integer) As Integer
    Parents.Peek.Nodes.Add(Node)
    Parents.Push(Node)

    Return Level
  End Function



  <Extension>
  Public Function ToFormat(Template As String, ParamArray Values As Object()) As String
    Return String.Format(Template, Values)
  End Function
End Module
```